# Kafka - Flume - Oracle Database - Error reading field 'throttle_time_ms'

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

The following are the versions that we are using.

kafka - 2.10-0.8.2.2
flume - 1.7.0
zookeeper - 3.4.6

When we try to incrementally download data from an Oracle database, i keep getting the following error

```
(kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [ERROR - 
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:130)] 
Uncaught error in kafka producer I/O thread:
org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'throttle_time_ms': java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.Schema.read(Schema.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleCompletedReceives(NetworkClient.java:439)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:216)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The following are my Flume configuration

```
agent.channels.ch1.capacity = 100000
agent.channels.ch1.transactionCapacity=10000
agent.sources.sql-source.incremental.column.name =  customer_id
agent.sources.sql-source.incremental.value =  1000
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.kafka.topic=customer_topic
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.channel=ch1
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.flumeBatchSize=1000
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.kafka.producer.acks=1
```

When searched in this forum for that error message, many were referring to some version mismatch. I am not sure which server version is that. We cannot change versions easily. Is there something (a workaround) that is available to make incremental ingest into Kafka topic work please.

Regards

bala

Answer (score 0):

Flume 1.7.0 User Guide:"This is a Flume Sink implementation that can publish data to a Kafka topic. One of the objective is to integrate Flume with Kafka so that pull based processing systems can process the data coming through various Flume sources. This currently supports Kafka 0.9.x series of releases.

This version of Flume no longer supports Older Versions (0.8.x) of Kafka."